# How do I convert from Local timezone to UTC in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-chrono

I am trying to convert my local time to UTC as below

```
fn main() {

    let nd_local = NaiveDate::from_ymd(2020,10,10).and_hms(10,10,10);
    let time_at_kolkata = Kolkata.from_local_datetime(&nd_local);


    println!("KOLKATA_TIME {:?}", time_at_kolkata);
    println!("UTC TIME {:?}", time_at_kolkata.naive_utc());

}
```

But it errors out as

```
println!("UTC TIME {:?}", time_at_kolkata.naive_utc());
   |                                               ^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `LocalResult<DateTime<Tz>>`
```

Here I am trying to convert it to `naive_utc`.
But generally how do I convert my `Kolkata` datetime to a `DateTime<Utc>` instance ?

Comment: May you add your `use`s to the code?

Answer (score 1):

> But it errors out as

> ```
> println!("UTC TIME {:?}", time_at_kolkata.naive_utc());
>    |                                               ^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `LocalResult<DateTime<Tz>>`
> ```

Look at the error message. You're expecting a `DateTime` but it clearly tells you that it has a `LocalResult<Datetime<Tz>>`.

This is because [`from_local_datetime` is faillible](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/offset/trait.TimeZone.html#method.from_local_datetime):

> Converts the local `NaiveDateTime` to the timezone-aware `DateTime` **if possible**.

emphasis mine, [some naive datetimes don't map any date in the timezone, and some are ambiguous](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/offset/enum.LocalResult.html) (can map to multiple dates in the timezone). You need to decide [whether](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/offset/enum.LocalResult.html#method.unwrap) and how you will handle those situations.

That aside,

> But generally how do I convert my `Kolkata` datetime to a `DateTime<Utc>` instance ?

As noted above, you don't currently have a "Kolkata datetime", so you need to fix that. I'm not actually sure why you're going through `NaiveDateTime` then localising that since [`TimeZone` has the `ymd`/`and_hms`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/offset/trait.TimeZone.html#method.ymd) builders. So you should be able to directly ask for "October 10th 2020 at 10:10:10 in the Kolkata timezone":

```
Kolkata::ymd(2020, 10, 10).and_hms(10, 10, 10)
```

Then, you can use [`with_timezone`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#method.with_timezone) to "move" the datetime around.